# The task is to write a java program to test if an array contains a specific value in java

Tags: java, arrays, loops

I got confused and didn't know what to add or change the loops.
Can someone please help me and tell me what I should do in order to run my code? It would be a big help to me. I'm only a beginner in Java...

## **here's my code: **

public static void main(String[] args) {

```
 Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
 int i,x;
 System.out.print("Input the size of the array: ");
 int size = input.nextInt(); 
 int num [] = new int [size];  /* declaration */
 
  System.out.println("Enter "+ size + " values: \n");
   for(i=0; i < num.length; i++){ 
      x = input.nextInt();
     num[i]=x;
   if ( num [i] == x );
   }
   System.out.print("Enter the search value: ");
   int search = input.nextInt();
     
 if ( num[i] == search){
     System.out.println (search + " is found in the array!");
 }
 else{ 
     System.out.println ("Your number is not in the array.");
    
 }
}
```

}

The sample output of my task is (using scanner):

Input the size of the array: 4
Enter the values:

14
15
16
17

Enter the search value: 14

14 is found in your input array.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
    int i,x;
    System.out.print("Input the size of the array: ");
    int size = input.nextInt(); 
    int num [] = new int [size];  /* declaration */
    
    //  System.out.println("Enter "+ size + " values: \n");
    for(i=0; i < num.length; i++){ 
        System.out.println("Enter Number to add at index "+i+" : ");
         x = input.nextInt();
        num[i]=x;
    }
    System.out.print("Enter the search value: ");
    int search = input.nextInt();
    boolean condition=false;
    for(i=0; i < num.length; i++){
        if ( num[i] == search){
            condition=true;
            break;
        }
    }
    if(condition==true){
        System.out.println("Number is Array!");
    }
    else{
        System.out.println("Number is not in array");
    }
}
```

your code is to be like this
there is logical error's in your code

1. to find an element you must traverse through array which can be achieved using loop so the last if else statement in your code must be in a loop
2. as due to the post increment in first loop after the completion of loop the value of i is one greater than last index of array so in if else statement at `if ( num[i] == search)` index is not found in array due to which it generates error.

for example I enter array size 3 and at num[0] I enter 1 at num[1] I enter 2 and at num[2] I enter 3 after the loop finishes the value of i become 3 when it come to conditional statement (if else) so it become `if(num[3] == search )` but 3 index is not present in array so it generates error.

Answer (score 0):

You need a loop to compare each element of the array with the search value.

```java
boolean found = false;
for (int x : num) 
    if (x == search) {
        found = true;
        break;
    }
System.out.println(found ? search + " is found in the array!" : "Your number is not in the array.");
```

Alternatively, with streams:

```java
System.out.println(Arrays.stream(num).anyMatch(x -> x == search) ?
 search + " is found in the array!" : "Your number is not in the array.");
```

Answer (score -1):

```
Scanner input = new Scanner (System.in);    
int i,x;
     System.out.print("Input the size of the array: ");
     int size = input.nextInt(); 
     int num [] = new int [size];  /* declaration */
     
      System.out.println("Enter "+ size + " values: \n");
        for (i = 0; i < num.length; i++) 
        {
            x = input.nextInt();
            num[i] = x;
            if (num[i] == x);
        }
        System.out.print("Enter the search value: ");
        int search = input.nextInt();
        
        boolean flag=false;
        for( i=0;i<num.length;i++) 
        {
            if (num[i] == search) {
                flag = true;
                System.out.println(num[i]+" is found in your input array");
                break;
            
            }
        }
        if (flag==false) 
        {
      System.out.println("Your number is not in the array.");
        }
}

[Screenshot][1]
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).